# I want to build a research question template with cleveref

Tags: templates, cleveref, capitalization

I want to build a template for research questions and sub-questions, which I can reuse in different papers. I want it to have the following features:

- automatically number them, make them referencable with cleveref
- spell the full RQ out at least twice in different sections (without increasing their counters, or building new labels)

I succeeded mostly with the following code, but I am unhappy with some things:

- cleveref does not respect my definition, to always capitalize "RQ" (in the very bottom sentence). **Can I make cleveref treat both `\Question` and `subQuestion` the same type of counter, or make it respect the capitalization?**
- I have to manually pass a dummy argument, the first time I define an RQ. Is there a better way? **Can LaTeX notice a first invocation of a command?**
- Each question/sub-questions definition is quite long and awkward. **Can you think of a more elegant way?**

[image: My current output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{rqcounter}{RQ}{RQs}
\crefname{rqcounter}{RQ}{RQs}
\Crefname{subrqcounter}{RQ}{RQs}
\Crefname{subrqcounter}{RQ}{RQs}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{rqcounter}
\newcounter{subrqcounter}
\renewcommand\thesubrqcounter{\arabic{rqcounter}.\arabic{subrqcounter}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Question}{omm}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\def\labelorref{\ref{#3}}}{\def\labelorref{\refstepcounter{rqcounter}\setcounter{subrqcounter}{0}\arabic{rqcounter}\label{#3}}}
    \noindent\textit{\textbf{RQ\labelorref:} #2\\}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\subQuestion}{omm}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\def\labelorref{\ref{#3}}}{\def\labelorref{\refstepcounter{subrqcounter}\arabic{rqcounter}.\arabic{subrqcounter}\label{#3}}}
    \noindent\textit{\textbf{RQ\labelorref:} #2\\}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rqone}{o}{
\def\myref{rq:one}
\def\qtext{How to make \textbackslash cleveref respect my capitalization rules?}
\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\Question{\qtext}{\myref}}{\Question[#1]{\qtext}{\myref}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rqoneone}{o}{
\def\myref{rq:one:one}
\def\qtext{Is there a way to not pass a dummy argument for first time invocation?}
\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\subQuestion{\qtext}{\myref}}{\subQuestion[#1]{\qtext}{\myref}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rqonetwo}{o}{
\def\myref{rq:one:two}
\def\qtext{Is there a way to make the definitions more elegant?}
\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\subQuestion{\qtext}{\myref}}{\subQuestion[#1]{\qtext}{\myref}}
}


\section{Methods}
Here, I introduce and give more details to the following research questions (RQ):\\
\rqone[firsttime]
\rqoneone[firsttime]
\rqonetwo[firsttime]

\section{Results}
Here I come back to my research questions, and answer them:\\
\rqone
I can't for now.\\
\rqoneone
\rqonetwo

\section{Discussion}
As we have seen: \Cref{rq:one,rq:one:one,rq:one:two} are not solved by me, yet.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think, I can solve my sub-questions 1.1 and 1.2 with the `@ifundefined` command, similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319437/how-to-test-if-a-label-exists

Comment: No, with the `@ifundefined` idea, the labels get created and removed after each compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571674/create-a-label-if-reference-undefined-else-reference-it-unique-label), I can define a custom "label", which can be looked up, whether it is defined.

The capitalization can be fixed with using `\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}`. This leaves RQs and sub-RQs in different reference types, but this seems fine, to me.

Altogether the following is produced by my new code [image: new output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\crefname{rqcounter}{RQ}{RQs}
\crefname{rqcounter}{RQ}{RQs}
\Crefname{subrqcounter}{RQ}{RQs}
\Crefname{subrqcounter}{RQ}{RQs}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{rqcounter}
\newcounter{subrqcounter}
\renewcommand\thesubrqcounter{\arabic{rqcounter}.\arabic{subrqcounter}}

\makeatletter%
\newcommand{\iflabelexists}[3]{\@ifundefined{myr@#1}{#2}{#3}}%
\makeatother%

\newcommand\Question[2]{%
\def\labelorref{\iflabelexists{#1}{\refstepcounter{rqcounter}\setcounter{subrqcounter}{0}\arabic{rqcounter}\label{#1}\expandafter\xdef\csname myr@#1\endcsname{}}{\ref{#1}}}
  \noindent\textit{\textbf{RQ\labelorref:} #2\\}%
}

\newcommand\subQuestion[2]{%
\def\labelorref{\iflabelexists{#1}{\refstepcounter{subrqcounter}\arabic{rqcounter}.\arabic{subrqcounter}\label{#1}\expandafter\xdef\csname myr@#1\endcsname{}}{\ref{#1}}}
  \noindent\textit{\textbf{RQ\labelorref:} #2\\}%
}

\newcommand\rqone{\Question{rq:one}{How to make cleveref respect my capitalization rules?}}

\newcommand\rqoneone{\subQuestion{rq:one:one}{Is there a way to not pass a dummy argument for first time invocation?}}

\newcommand\rqonetwo{\subQuestion{rq:one:two}{Is there a way to make the definitions more elegant?}}

\section{Methods}
Here, I introduce and give more details to the following research questions (RQ):\\
\rqone
\rqoneone
\rqonetwo

\section{Results}
Here I come back to my research questions, and answer them:\\
\rqone
I can't for now.\\
\rqoneone
\rqonetwo

\section{Discussion}
As we have seen: \Cref{rq:one,rq:one:one,rq:one:two} are not solved by me, yet.

\end{document}
```